# Function produces expected type '(() -> ())?'; did you mean to call it with '()'?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

> Function produces expected type '(() -> ())?'; did you mean to call it with '()'?

I am getting the above error. Auto fix from Xcode does not help.

The error is on `self.performOnCommunicationQueue()`:

```
func getAuthParams(authClosure:((error:NSError?) -> ())?) {
    logDebug("Starting sync session with Max device")

    if let statusError = self.assertReady() {
        logError("Start sync session failed with error: \(statusError)")

        if (authClosure != nil) {
            authClosure!(error: statusError)
        }
    } else {
        self.performOnCommunicationQueue() {
            let error:NSError?

            // Set random starting byte
            let oAbsTime:[UInt64] = [mach_absolute_time()]
            let payload:NSData = NSData(bytes: oAbsTime, length: 8)
            let absTime:UInt8 = UnsafePointer<UInt8>(payload.bytes).memory
            self.randomCryptoByte = (0x01 | ( absTime & 0xfe))
    }
}

func sendAuthChallenge(authChal:String, completion:((error:NSError?) -> ())?) {
}

func performOnCommunicationQueue(closure:(()->())?){
    if (closure != nil)
    {
        self.communicationQueue?.addOperationWithBlock(closure!)
    }
}
```

Comment: `self.performOnCommunicationQueue() {` Is the brace here a typo? If not, what are you expecting to do. This doesn't match anywhere further down, and if it did, I think it would only serve to isolate the scope of the lines below.

Comment: func performOnCommunicationQueue(closure:(()->())?){
  if (closure != nil)
  {
   self.communicationQueue?.addOperationWithBlock(closure!)
  }
 }

This is the function trying to be called

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
self.performOnCommunicationQueue({ () -> () in
    let error:NSError?
    // Set random starting byte
    let oAbsTime:[UInt64] = [mach_absolute_time()]
    let payload:NSData = NSData(bytes: oAbsTime, length: 8)
    let absTime:UInt8 = UnsafePointer<UInt8>(payload.bytes).memory
    self.randomCryptoByte = (0x01 | ( absTime & 0xfe))
})
```

This creates the void to void closure that `performOnCommunicationQueue` requires.

Also, check that your braces match up once you've made this change, I think you might be one short, which is why autocomplete wasn't a help.